# How do I get changing data as a result from a service to use in an activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am trying to design a proximity alert app which notifies with an alarm in case the user enters a school zone and is driving above a certain speed while he enters.

I need to run a background service which calculates user location and speed.

I need an activity to receive the user's constantly changing latitude/longitude and speed values, and use these values to calculate distance between current location and school location(coordinates of which will be received from a database) and sound an alarm if the distance is lesser than the already set proximity radius.

Answer (score 1):

Whats your problem?
I have done this in one of my last project.
You have to implement a GPS listener in your service.
I woul recommend a Broadcast for communication between your service and your activity.
If you want an alarm, if your activity is in view you have to implement your alarm in the activity. Otherwise you have to create an pendingIntent in your service and fire a notification if its time for.

possible onCreate in your service:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {

    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myServiceBroadcastReceiver = new MyServiceBroadcastReceiver();
    MyApplication.getAppContext().registerReceiver(myServiceBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyApplication.APP_UPDATE_DEMAND));

    myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);




    myLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    myLocListener = new MyLocListener();


    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MyApplication.GPS_UPDATE_PERIOD, 0, myLocListener);
    myLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MyApplication.NETWORK_UPDATE_PERIOD, 0, myLocListener);  // comment this line out if you want only gps!   
}
```

Your example LocationListener class

```
    private class MyLocListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        String lng = Double.toString(location.getLongitude();
//evaluate lat and lng here, fire a notification or send a broadcast if the activity is in view.

        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // Do something 

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // Do something 

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
            Bundle extras) {
    // Do something 
    }
}
```

If you want evaluate lat and lng in the service (activity is not in view) you can do this in onLocationChanged() if you want to evaluate your gps data in your activity (is in view) you could send a broadcast to your activity.
There are other possibilities to give data to the activity, but for me the solution with a broadcast was the best option (had to send other information too).